# Is it possible to have multiple angular applications within a repo that all use the same outside "shell"?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

By shell I mean the same header component and authentication methods. What I'm trying to do is create an application that is sort of like the AWS console - a bunch of services on the same page. On the AWS console, you always have the toolbar at the top but the contents change.

I setup this project by using the angular cli to generate several applications that go under the projects folder. I then have an src/app folder that has my main application shell (the header component, authentication, main landing page, etc). However, when I route from the main landing page to one of the applications, the header goes away and it's just whatever is in the application that is left (page with the service name for now).

Is there any way to load these sub applications within the context of the base app module?

My application structure

```
- projects
  - project 1
    - src/app
  - project 2
    - src/app
  - project 3
    - src/app
- src
  - app
```

Comment: Wouldnt that be a nightmare for trying to deploy it?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure how else you would be able to deploy it with many applications?

Comment: You definitely want to keep individual applications separate. There are a lot of files angular cli generates for you and mixing them would make for a big mess. Why dont you instead of trying to create a bunch of different angular apps, in your scr/ create different folder representing each specific angular 'module' that can be its own mini project.

Comment: Yeah that's kind of what we have now. I was just looking into how you make the code even more separate. And some of the individual applications can then have their own tslint rules if they wanted and if they need different environment file properties, to keep those separate.

Comment: hmm. Not sure if thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is can be easily resolved with routes and "router outlet" for navigation, as far as having separate applications, this is kind of the main principle of Angular and is done in just about every application by "lazy loading feature modules".

It sounds to me like you want to turn your applications into modules that can be easily loaded by the main application. *I should also mention that it not uncommon to find yourself having to do this and conversion is not that painful once you understand the module format.*